# SET SCAN OFF purpose

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Can anyone please explain what is the purpose of SET SCAN OFF and SET SCAN ON? I know its purpose is to disable substitution variables and parameters, but I want a clear explanation.

Answer (score 12):

`SET SCAN` is obsolete but it was used to control whether or not it should scan for substitution params/variables. `OFF` would prevent scanning for params/variables.

`SET DEFINE` replaces/extends the functionality and a good writeup is here: http://shaharear.blogspot.com/2009/01/set-define.html

From the website

> set define on;
>
> select '&hello' from dual;
>
> If define is set to on and SQL*Plus finds the current substitution
>   prefix, it asks for a string to be entered. In the following example,
>   I entered: hasan
>
> Enter value for hello: this string was entered

```
 old 1: select '&hello' from dual 
 new 1: select 'this string was entered' from dual
```

This is equivalent to how the old `SET SCAN` would work. Basically you're controlling whether or not to prompt for a substitution

Comment: Is DEFINE set to ON by default?

Answer (score 4):

In SQL*Plus (and various other tools that support SQL*Plus syntax), by default, the tool scans SQL statements looking for substitution variables.  This allows you to create SQL*Plus scripts that use variables defined in SQL*Plus for various reporting tasks.

Because substitution variables begin with the ampersand ('&') and need not be declared in advance, however, that creates problems if you are trying to run a SQL statement that happens to include an ampersand.  For example, if you've got an `INSERT` statement that happens to have a string literal that includes an ampersand, you don't want SQL*Plus to pre-process the statement.  Or, if I want to select the string "foo & bar"

```
SQL> set scan off;
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1* select 'foo & bar' from dual
SQL> /

'FOO&BAR'
---------
foo & bar
```

If I allow SQL*Plus to pre-process the statement, however, the text '& bar' is interpreted as a substitution variable and I'm prompted to enter the text to substitute at runtime

```
SQL> set scan on
SQL> /
Enter value for bar: some value
old   1: select 'foo & bar' from dual
new   1: select 'foo some value' from dual

'FOOSOMEVALUE'
--------------
foo some value
```

Answer (score -2):

SQL> set scan on SQL> /Enter value for bar: some value old 1: select 'foo & bar' from dual new 1: select 'foo some value' from dual

'FOOSOMEVALUE' --------------foo some value